# Calculate matrix $A_{a+b\vartheta}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $\mathbb{Q}[\vartheta]=\{a+b\vartheta:a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$ be the smallest subring of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\vartheta$, where $\vartheta$ is a real or complex number. Calculate for $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ the matrix $A_{a+b\vartheta}$ of the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $\mathbb{Q}[\vartheta] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[\vartheta],\ x\mapsto (a+b\vartheta)x$ with respect to the $\mathbb{Q}$-basis $1,\vartheta$ of $\mathbb{Q}[\vartheta]$.

I want to calculate this matrix but I'm a little bit lost because I'm not sure how to do it.

My approach would be to look at the standard base $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and the $\mathbb{Q}-$base $\{\binom{1}{0},\binom{0}{\vartheta}\}$.

Then, $(1,0)\binom{1}{0}+(0,1)\binom{0}{\vartheta}=1+\vartheta \mapsto(a+b\vartheta)(1+\vartheta) = a+\vartheta(a+b+b\vartheta) =(a,0)\binom{1}{0}+(0,a+b+b\vartheta)\binom{0}{\vartheta}$.

Therefore, $A_{a+b\vartheta}=\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a+b+b\vartheta}$

I hope that's correct. If not, can someone lead me in the right direction?

EDIT:

$\vartheta = \cases{\sqrt{d} \quad \text{ if } d \equiv 2,3 \mod 4\\\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{d}) \quad \text{ if }d\equiv 1 \mod 4}$

$d\neq 1$ is a [square-free integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer).

Comment: As $1\mapsto a+b\vartheta$ the first column should be $(a,b)^T$. Until you tell us what $\vartheta^2$ is we can't tell you the second column.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do the first case.

$$
A_{a+b\vartheta}(1)=a\cdot 1+ b\cdot\vartheta
\text{ and }
A_{a+b\vartheta}(\vartheta)=b\vartheta^2+a\cdot\vartheta=bd\cdot 1+a\cdot\vartheta
$$
so by the definition of "matrix" we have
$$
\text{Mat}_{1,\vartheta}^{1,\vartheta}(A_{a+b\vartheta})=\begin{pmatrix} a & bd\\ b & a\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The other case is done the same way, once we notice that $\vartheta^2=\frac{d-1}{4}+\vartheta$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it now. So in the second case the matrix is $\pmatrix{a&b\frac{d-1}{4}\\b&a+b}$?